# Получение данных ajax запросом

Tags: php, javascript

Вообщем есть ajax запрос:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){

 $.ajax({
     url: '/index.php',
     data: {....},
     type:'POST',
     cache: false,
     success: function(data){
         if(data == 1)
         {
            .....
         }
     }
 });
```

И файл который обрабатывает этот запрос и возвращает значение:

```
<?
    function(...){
      ....
      return 1;
    }
?>
```

Но возвращает он ее только если поместить его в `echo` (Например: `echo 1;` и тогда результат запроса, `data` будет равно единице), но в моем случае это не подходит. Как сделать так чтобы запрос возвращал булево значение?

Comment: А почему "но в моем случае это не подходит"? Ваш код выглядит нормально: 1 как true, 0 - false. Можно, конечно, и строку передавать "true" и "false", разницы нет.

Comment: @larrymacbarry, Проблема в том что если я возвращаю строку с помощью `echo`, например: `echo '1';` то потом в самой форме отображается `1`, что мне не нужно. Не знаю как сделать так чтобы `echo` возвращало значение и в то же время не отображалось

Comment: А почему у вас 1 отображается в форме? Напишите отдельный обработчик формы form.php, который был делал echo 1 или 0 и служил бы только для обработки запросов, и обращайтесь к нему с помощью ajax с главной страницы. Данные из echo  будут прилетать прямо в success: function(data){  console.log(data)}

Answer (score 6):

Если коротко - то никак.

Ajax - это обмен между клиентом (браузером) и сервером посредством XmlHttpRequest, который, сильно упрощая, есть текст. Никаких булевых переменных, объектов, массивов, чисел с плавающей точкой там быть не может по определению. А ещё потому, что эти сущности имеют в общем случае разное битовое представление на сервере (где не обязательно php, а что угодно) и в браузере (где js).

Если сильно хочется, то можно данные на сервере запаковать в JSON, а в браузере их распаковать.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо! А что и как можно сделать, чтобы данные отправлялись и обрабатывались по принципу ajax запросов, но возвращали true или false. Вообщем я хочу сделать каптчу, ajax ом я отправлял данные из формы на проверку и возвращал результат, как это можно по другому реализовать?

Comment: Ну, во-первых, почитайте про json. А во-вторых, я не вижу разницы между if (response) и if (response=='ok')

Comment: Не забываем про http коды. Можно 404 вернуть как ресурс не найден...

Comment: @KAGG Design, Проблема в том что если я возвращаю строку, например: `echo 1`  то потом в самой форме отображается `1`, что мне не нужно. Хотел сделать так чтобы это все выводилось в какой-нибудь div с классом hidden, но пока не получается(

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, хотя я и не понимаю, зачем результат выводить в поле формы.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый зеленой галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.